# Dynamically resize rounded div in Bootstrap column

Tags: html, css

I have a div named `profile-picture-container` and a picture inside it.
The div has an explicit width and height, and the `border-radius` set to 50% to make it a circle.

I place this div in a `Bootstrap(3.3.7)` col. Since it has an explicit width and height for example 100px, when I resize the window, and bootstrap jumps to a smaller grid setting, the `profile-picture-container` overflows the column. As far as I know, to make a div a circle, its height and width needs to be the same.

However I can't use percentages since setting the width to 70% is ok, but setting the height to 70% is a totally different size, since it sets to the column's height's 70%.
Is there a way to make it dynamic and avoid writing many media queries?

```css
.profile-picture-container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #222;
}
.col-sm-9 {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="profile-picture-container">
                    <img src="assets/face-1.jpg" class="profile-picture" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Consequuntur temporibus amet
                ad dolor fuga tenetur veniam magni quo totam facilis blanditiis suscipit iusto debitis vero nam
                necessitatibus possimus ut odit tempora aliquam ullam natus, officiis tempore dignissimos. Unde et
                obcaecati magnam consectetur, velit, deleniti excepturi, error optio id est porro? Ea modi rem accusamus
                debitis atque nihil quaerat ad sed labore cum, impedit blanditiis consequuntur! Quia molestias aliquid
                velit iure possimus consectetur! Nostrum atque, dolores doloremque eius commodi ducimus reprehenderit
                repellendus ratione! Reprehenderit unde fugit, quisquam magni ducimus culpa corrupti aut explicabo
                tenetur alias quo expedita quod corporis, officiis quos!</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: can you put your code here?

Comment: @mohsensolhnia sure, I inserted it

Comment: If I understand correctly. You're struggling to set the desired height of the circle. Setting the height to X% won't help. Have you tried to use `vw` (verwport width) to set the height? It may create some more problems with scaling, but then the width/height of the circle would always be the same. This unit represents the actual rendered width of your website (in percents).

Answer (score 0):

Specify image height and width in `img` tag.

```
<img src="assets/face-1.jpg" class="profile-picture" alt="" width="200" height="200">
```

And for css add this following **css** to get solution.

```
.profile-picture-container{
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 1;
   padding-bottom: 100%;
}
.profile-picture-container img{
   bottom: 0;
   display: block;
   height: 100%;
   left: 0;
   margin: auto;
   max-width: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   border-radius: 50%;
   width: 100%;
}
```